# Let $f$ is a continuously differentiable function then what can we say about the function $\frac{1}{f}$ ?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ is a continuously differentiable function then what can we say about the function $\frac{1}{f}$ ? Does it imply that $\frac {1}{f}$ is also continuously differentiable ?

Comment: The function $f(x) = x$ defined on the reals is continuously differentiable (smooth, even), but $1/f$ is not even continuous everywhere, let alone continuously differentiable.

Comment: Clearly not. If $f$ is zero somewhere, then $\frac{1}{f}$ is not even defined!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very false if $f$ is ever zero, and you should be able to find counterexamples. For a related question, though, suppose $f(x) \ne 0$ on some interval; then after noting that

$$\left(\frac 1 f\right)' = - \frac{f'}{f^2}$$

you should check that $1/f$ is indeed continuous on this interval.

It follows from the fact that

> $f'$ and $f^2$ are both continuous, and $f^2 \ne 0$, and a quotient of continuous functions with non-vanishing denominator is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=x$ is continuously differentiable, however $\frac1{f(x)}=\frac1x$ isn't even continuous.